# Passing data between controllers using combine not working

Tags: swift, combine

I am starting on combine with swift, but having some hard time (had experience working in swiftui before).
So the question is how to perform certain operation:

1. lets say i have vc1. and I go to vc2 from there
   2.then i start asynchronos network closure and come back to vc1 (by popping out vc2).
2. Now say i want to ge just a string from vc2's asycnrhoss clousre to vc1 when i am back to vc1.
   how can i achieve this?

I want to use publisher of lets say <String, Never>
how can I subscribe in my vc1 and publish or send it from vc2 ?

**I am using this approach but its not working, it never comes to code under sink.....**

```
public class Parent {
   public  static let shared = Parent()
   public var publisher = PassthroughSibject<String,Never>()
}

class vc1: ViewController {
   func viewdidLoad() {
     let subscription = Parent.shared.oublisehr.sink { (result) in
     print(result)
     }
  }
  func navigatetoVC1() {
  ///// some code to navigate to vc1
  }

  func button() {
    self.navigatetoVC1
  }

}


class vc2: ViewController {

   func viewDidload() {
   ///
   }
  func performsomeOperation() {
     someasyncoperation(completion: { result in
       switch result {
       case .success:
         //send some data to vc1
         Parent.shared.publisher.send("testdata")
       case .failure:
       //send some data to vc1
    })
  self.dismisVC2() //some method to pop out vc2
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right, except you are using your **Anycancellable** inside viewdidload, so its scope is getting exhausted. So use it outside in the view controller as an optional AnyCancellable type.
Below code should work.

```
class vc1: ViewController {
var subscription = AnyCancellable?

   func viewdidLoad() {
     self.subscription = Parent.shared.oublisehr.sink { (result) in
         print(result)
     }
   }
  func navigatetoVC1() {
  ///// some code to navigate to vc1
  }

  func button() {
    self.navigatetoVC1
  }

}
```

Comment: can you share some sample code or some article?

Comment: I have one more question, does it is good practice to use the singleton view model?